# AJAX get function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Help me get a text field number then make a multiplication table of the number. using AJAX in jQuery.  The below script is not working for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numValue = $("#num").val();
    $.get("path.php", {number: numValue} , function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Please show what you retrieve in the `data` variable.

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working? Is there an error, or `data` is something you didn't expect?

Comment: "The below script is not working for me" is a useless thing to tell us.  Useful information would be what it *does* do.. any error messages that may be on the javascript console..

Comment: @jeremy just change the path to point to your page "../php/create-table.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to get a html element value then request the server then display the fetched details to your browser
below is the whole example and i have included the script in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>AJAX</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

              $("button").click(function(){

            // Get value from input element on the page
               var numValue = $("#num").val();

            // Send the input data to the server using get
              $.get("../php/create-table.php", {number: numValue} , function(data){

           // Display the returned data in browser
              $("#result").html(data);

    });

  });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

   <label>A number Between 10 t0 100 <input type="text" id="num"></label>

    <button type="button">Generate Table</button>

         <div id="result"></div>

     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: cool Ahy, @jeremy just change the path to point to your page "../php/create-table.php"